# how to get classpath from mp3 within a jar file

Tags: java, jar, mp3, classpath, embedded-resource

I've got a problem with my classpath within a jar file. With pictures
`getClass().getResource("picture.png")` works fine. But I need to get a mp3 file.
If I put in the whole path outside of the jar file it works just fine, however if i try it
 without the full path like `getClass().getResource("picture.png")` it says "File not Found".
So I'm looking for a solution for the path of song.mp3 so that if I build the .jar and open it on a different computer the song still plays.

this is my code:

```
package bgmusic;

import java.io.*;

import javax.media.Format;
import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.MediaLocator;
import javax.media.Player;
import javax.media.PlugInManager;
import javax.media.format.AudioFormat;

public class Bgmusic {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Format input1 = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.MPEGLAYER3);
        Format input2 = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.MPEG);
        Format output = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.LINEAR);
        PlugInManager.addPlugIn(
            "com.sun.media.codec.audio.mp3.JavaDecoder",
            new Format[]{input1, input2},
            new Format[]{output},
            PlugInManager.CODEC
        );
        try{
            Player player = Manager.createPlayer(new MediaLocator(new File("song.mp3").toURI().toURL()));
            player.start();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is inside of your jar, you can not use `new File("song.mp3");`.  The file expects it to be inside of your normal os path, which it's not.

To get files from within your jar you need to use `getResource`

Example, assuming song.mp3 is in the root of your jar file and not in a directory:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("song.mp3");
```

From within a static method you should be able to get it as follows

```
URL url = BgMusic.class.getResource("song.mp3");
```

Comment: When I try that i seem to get an error <indentifier> expected
and if i try
 InputStream is; 
                        is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream.("/song.mp3");
how do i put it in the player?

Comment: apologies, you should use getResource in this case as opposed to getResourceAsStream.  getResource returns a URL which can be used directly with MediaLocator

Comment: Im getting a non static variable cannot be referenced from a static context now:
InputStream is; 
is = this.getClass().getResource("/song.mp3");

Comment: First,notice the updated answer you need a URL.  Also I didn't notice you were inside of your static void main.  answer updated